# How to count the number of a particular entry. python

Tags: python

Im trying to count the "elite" key, the number of entry with "elite" key that is not empty. and then total the number of "elite" user.

the following is the example data set which should have "1" because there is "1" entry out of 3 that have elite that is not an empty list.

```
{"yelping_since": "2013-07", "votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 2, "cool": 2}, "review_count": 5, "name": "Kikki", "user_id": "KW35l9DVkPNJCgApafhE8w", "friends": [], "fans": 0, "average_stars": 3.67, "type": "user", "compliments": {}, "elite": [2012]}
{"yelping_since": "2013-10", "votes": {"funny": 0, "useful": 0, "cool": 0}, "review_count": 1, "name": "Cindy", "user_id": "OdajpYB_nAJXNLSNbyMvxg", "friends": [], "fans": 0, "average_stars": 5.0, "type": "user", "compliments": {}, "elite": []}
{"yelping_since": "2013-10", "votes": {"funny": 0, "useful": 0, "cool": 0}, "review_count": 3, "name": "Lawrence", "user_id": "z-0l9wtrlGBSyMlj4BP9Lw", "friends": [], "fans": 0, "average_stars": 3.5, "type": "user", "compliments": {}, "elite": []}
```

the following is the code that i have tried

```
import json

def count_number_of_elite():

    with open("data/yelp_academic_dataset_user.txt", "r") as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if json.loads(line)["elite"]:
                number_of_elite_user += 1

print (number_of_elite_user)
```

Comment: The code you provide isn't valid Python. Also you are never executing the function, so why would you expect anything to happen?

Comment: what do you propose to do?

Comment: Learn how to write valid Python code? You are honestly getting the very basics wrong, so you should consult a tutorial at this point.

Comment: [Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a detailed description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *does not work*, *please help me* are not acceptable.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input data is in json format, I'd use

```
import json

file = open("data/yelp_academic_dataset_checkin", "r")

for line in file:
    if json.loads(line)["elite"] != []:
        number_of_elite_user += 1
        return number_of_elite_user
```

Also the return statement should probably not be in the for-loop, since otherwise it'll always return 1.

Along with improvements that @UnholySheep suggested below in comments, the right way of that code would be:

```
import json

def count_lines():
    number_of_elite_user = 0
    with open("data/yelp_academic_dataset_checkin", "r") as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if json.loads(line)["elite"]:
                number_of_elite_user += 1
    return number_of_elite_user

print(count_lines())
```

Comment: `!= []` is unnecessary - an empty list evaluate to `False` in Python. Also it's preferable to open the file using `with open() as`. And `file` is a bad name as it hides a built-in function

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've just copied the code that the OP included in the question and made the small change so that the issue resolves.

Comment: I've included your proposed changes to the answer.

Comment: ive tried your code @table but it still didnt work. it did not produce any ouput. the output should be 1. because there is 1 elite with an entry of 2012. and the other two is just an empty list. i re posted the whole code up in the question.

Comment: The code you provided does not produce any output. Perhaps you've mistyped `return` for `print`.

Comment: I think both of you forgot to define the variable you are trying to return (which would lead to an exception being thrown). Also please don't use the same name for a variable and the function.

Comment: i tried changing it to print (number_of_elite_user) it still did not work. the full code i posted in the question again

Comment: so maybe use "count" as variable @u

Answer (score 1):

the code bellow does what you want:

first make sure to import json:

```
import json
```

and change the body of your function to this:

```
file = open("data/yelp_academic_dataset_checkin", "r")

number_of_elite_user = 0

for line in file:
    user = json.loads(line)
    if (len(user['elite'])>0):
        number_of_elite_user += 1

return number_of_elite_user
```